# Organize function into a class (by category)

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a class with some functions. The functions can be categorize in "NameSpace".
I search a way to organize each function into somekind of namespace into my class.
It was suggested to me to change my approach. Using Interface instead of inheritance.

Here some sample for be understand

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public string A = "A";
        public string B = "B";
        public int one = 1;
        public int two = 2;

        public Printer globalPrinter;


    }

public class Class10 : Class1
{
    public class Letter
    {
        public void FunctionA()
        {
            globalPrinter.print(A);
        }
        public void FunctionB()
        {
            globalPrinter.print(B);
        }
    }

    public class Number
    {

        public void Function1()
        {
            globalPrinter.print(one);
        }
        public void Function2()
        {
            globalPrinter.print(two);
        }
    }


}

public class ClassX : Class10
{
    public ClassX()
    {
        Letter.FunctionA();
        Letter.FunctionB();
        Number.Function1();
        Number.Function2();
    }
}

var c10 = new ClassX();
```

This code doesn't work. You could look, at the end of the sample, you'll see

```
  Letter.FunctionA();
  Letter.FunctionB();
  Number.Function1();
  Number.Function2();
```

I could simply put FunctionA and FunctionB inside Class10. But if there's 100 functions. It could be more interesting to split function into Categories.

Let me see your approach of the problem.

---

I added some item for helping the categorization.

---

Answer Full Code

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public string A = "A";
        public string B = "B";
        public int one = 1;
        public int two = 2;

        public void globalPrinter(object t)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Class10 : Class1
    {
        public class Letter
        {
            readonly Class10 parent;
            public Letter(Class10 parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
            }
            public void FunctionA()
            {
                parent.globalPrinter(parent.A);
            }
            public void FunctionB()
            {
                parent.globalPrinter(parent.B);
            }
        }

        public class Number
        {
               readonly Class10 parent;
               public Number(Class10 parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
            }
            public void Function1()
            {

                parent.globalPrinter(parent.one);
            }
            public void Function2()
            {
                parent.globalPrinter(parent.two);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassX : Class10
    {
        public ClassX()
        {
            new Letter(this).FunctionA();
            new Letter(this).FunctionB();
            new Number(this).Function1();
            new Number(this).Function2();                
        }
    }

    ClassX c10 = new ClassX();
```

Comment: The sample code you provide is a bit difficult to follow, and doesn't do much to demonstrate the semantics of the object(s) being modeled.  Depending on what you're trying to achieve, interfaces may indeed be part of the answer.  That is, if any given subset of the methods can be semantically grouped into a particular contract of functionality.  But it's impossible to know based on the example provided because it has no meaningful context.  Can you create a more real-world example and describe the issue a bit more clearly?

Comment: FunctionA(), FunctionB(), and FunctionC() will need to be static to call them without creating an instance of the class.  The same is true of the variables A and B in Class1.

Comment: I change my sample for more detail of the categorization.

Comment: If your class is going to have more than 100 functions it might have more than [a single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It just might.

Comment: it print number and letter. (its an example). 100 its a lot, it was just for made the point that theres more than just a few functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a sub class like `Class10.Letter` is not part of the inheritance hierarchy that its parent class `Class10` is part of.

So, `Class10.Letter` does not inherit from `Class1`, only `Class10` inherits from `Class1`, so `Class10.Letter` needs an instance of `Class1` or `Class10` so it can access `globalPrinter`

```
public class Class10: Class1 {
    public class Letter {
        readonly Class10 parent;
        public Letter(Class10 parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        public void FunctionA() {
            parent.globalPrinter.print(parent.A);
        }
    }
}
```

Also `ClassX` inherits from `Class10` so it has access to `Class10` functions, but it does not inherit from `Class10.Letter`, so`ClassX` needs an instance of `Letter` if it is calling non-static functions:

```
public ClassX() {
    new Letter(this).FunctionA();
    ...
```

Comment: I cant, Function A cant be static because it use non static variable of the current/parent object.

Comment: Well, you've changed the sample so now Class20 isn't defined.  In any case, if a function isn't static, you need to create an instance of the class with new.

Comment: your right, I change my sample, someone ask for in the comments. Yes, my "main class" ClassX, will be instantiate. Need to contain variable and set the globalPrinter.

Comment: new answer based on new sample code

Comment: The problem is before ClassX. You cant do globalPrinter.print(A); Its not accessible from its parent.

Comment: revised answer again

Comment: It worked, not quite fineness, I had thought of that. I just hope to control the simplicity of classes with function (Letter and Number). Now they need to have a parent declare, with constructor. I want to limit the content of those class. The inheritance should do everything, you just need to implement it and you can use those properties for whatever you want.